# Partitioning on Mac OS X (Yosemite)

Tags: partitioning, osx-yosemite

I am facing a strange problem in Mac OS X (Yosemite). I have 2 partitions but I am unable to understand how much space is being used up in the primary partition. Reports on Screens 2 and 3 are quite confusing.

I have attached screenshot from Disk Utility for you to understand and help me.

[image: screenshot]

Also, is it possible to extend the size of primary partition?